# Is linear algebra a formal system?

Tags: linear-algebra, formal-systems

By a formal system I mean a system for inferring theorems from axioms according to a set of rules. Essentially I wonder, whether a linear algebra could be viewed as some particular set of axioms from which by rules of inference I would generate all its theorems. Or is linear algebra just a field of mathematics dealing with linear equations and everything around them so that there could be more formal systems built around it? In my university, we don't learn to do formal proofs in linear algebra so I wonder whether  linear algebra could be formalized.

Note: I have just done a course in mathematical logic (model theory - first order logic, proof theory - Hilbert's calculus) and I've just started learning linear algebra. If there is anything unclear on my question, please let me know.

Comment: The phrase mathematics is an formal system is really an ambiguous question. The rules are proven to be correct, but there are always approximations that make result somewhat incorrect.  It's not a good idea, however, to hold on to the distinction between formal and not formal sciences since a probabilistic model can often be a better model than a deterministic one.

Comment: Mathematics generally proceeds from axioms and definitions to theorems, including the facts of linear algebra. Your course sounds like the "applied mathematics" version of linear algebra, but I would expect everything you learn in "linear algebra" to be based on theorems whose proofs you just have not seen, except perhaps when your class strays outside pure mathematics to apply its methods to real life.

Comment: There are several levels of mathematical rigor between what you probably see in your logic course and what you describe from your linear algebra course. You don't *have* to use a language like Hilbert calculus to proceed from axioms to theorems.

Comment: @NeDark I'm not sure what you're trying to say. A probabilistic model can be just as formal as a deterministic one. Either one is an unproved idealization if you attempt to use it to answer a problem in physics.